# Asp.net vb find XML nodes

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xpath

i have the below xml and i want to get the phone from each item. 
I have a loop where i can read the name and surname with success but i'm stacked on the other part.

Which is the xpath i should follow

```
<items>

<item>
    <name></name>
    <surname></surname>
    <list>
        <phone></phone>
        <email></email>
    </list>
</item>

<item>
    <name></name>
    <surname></surname>
    <list>
        <phone></phone>
        <email></email>
    </list>
</item>

</items>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

dom.xpath("//item").each do |item_node|

```
    name = item_node.xpath("./name")

    surname = item_node.xpath("./surname")

    phone = item_node.xpath("./list/phone")

    email = item_node.xpath("./list/email")
```

end